# Displaying one to many arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table in which there are 2 tables,

1. questions
2. answers

each question will have multiple answers

I am trying to get all the questions and answers in an array.  The below code is working. I am using a for loop inside a foreach, if some one point to improve the below code, it will be very helpful

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions AS q LEFT JOIN answers AS a ON q.question_id=a.question_id WHERE q.question_id=a.question_id AND category_id =:category_id";
    $stmt = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue('category_id',$category_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($data as $d){
        $qid = $d['question_id'];
        $q[$qid]['question'] = $d['question'];
        $q[$qid]['answers'][] = $d['answers'];
    }

            /*
            Checking the output, for send the $data when this function is called
    foreach($q as $id => $val){
        echo $val['question'] .'<br>';

        for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
            echo $val['answers'][$i];
        }
    }
           */
```

Comment: I Would use two SQL-queries. One for questions and one for answers if you get those like this in same query the same question is fetched multiple times (as many as there is answers to that) so it's not really nice.. With two queries this would be fetched faster from server and it would be easier to handle the output.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong about this code.

Comment: do you need select * ? or can you select sfecific fields

Comment: @HaimEvgi Evgi, i am selecting, all the fields, question_id, question, answer and answer_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this like (PSEUDO CODE):

```
$questions = get all questions
$answers = get all answers

$my_questions = array();

foreach ($questions as $q) {

  $my_questions[$q['id']] = array(
    'question' => $q['question'],
    'answers' => array()
  )
}

foreach ($answers as $a) {
  $my_questions[$a['question_id']]['answers'][$a['answer_id']] = $a['answer'];
}
```

So the result would be like:

```
[
  39 => [
    'question' => "Who am i?",
    'answers' => [
      53 => "I don't know",
      54 => "Who cares?"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I bet this is faster than joinin two tables in SQL. Also easier to handle and does not fetch any extra data from server.